# Create 3D models from real objects to use with openGL in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I want to implement an Android application that will show 3D objects using openGL. I worked with openGL some years ago, but then I used already defined objects, I never created them. Now I need to create those objects from real ones.

I've checked 3DSOM Pro since it seems quite easy to create those objects, but I'm not sure if then they can be represented as a set of vertices, normals, etc. Anybody knows if it's possible? Aside from that, I don't like the fact that it's not free.

So my question is, what are the most common programs to create 3D objects that can be used then in openGL? I'm interested in free and easy to use applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Blender](http://blender.org) is probably the most widely used free 3D editor.

Google SketchUp is very easy to use, but sold at reasonable price. I prefer it because I am not an expert in 3D modelling.

Comment: I've been looking Blender and it seems a really nice choice. I'm gonna try to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a software known as [Insight3d](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Finsight3d.sourceforge.net%2F&ei=njY7UYnXO5HKrAfJkIGoCw&usg=AFQjCNFglzN2zpwcrlXZMeu10suafD5dNA&sig2=v_KKsQ9UDeIpeaLZ5a6HiQ&bvm=bv.43287494,d.bmk&cad=rja) which can convert from multiple images to 3d objects.I personally compiled it and got seg faults . Maybe if you can fix those you can convert real to virtual objects in matter of minutes.

In case you want to create objects manually then I guess [Blender](http://blender.org/)(as suggested by Bartek) is a great software for creating 3d models with support for lot of addons. You can put background images of each orthographic views and then keep on drawing the isometric(3D) as you want to create from 3d models from real objects .

Using blender the objects can be converted to .obj wavefront format and can be imported to Opengl.